# Vagrant box not found

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, fedora

According to Magento PHP Developer's Guide, I have been setting up Vagrant with Virtualbox on a Fedora Workstation 22 setup.  This install went mostly as planned with the exception that I had to install a few kernel header files and libvirt related packages in order to get Virtualbox up and running.

Then I ran:

```
>vagrant box add lucid32 http://files.vagrantup.com/lucid32.box

>vagrant init lucid32 #A Vagrantfile is successfully created in my home directory

>vagrant up
```

Both as root and not as root.  vagrant up has permission issues when I do it without root.  As root, it is having trouble finding my box because it is looking in my home directory where the file does not exist.  My questions are:

1) Why is it looking in the wrong place (home)? Or,

2) Why has the box not been created in home? Or,

3) How can I specify the box location in a vagrant command or environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed by upgrading Vagrant from 1.7.2 to 1.7.3.